# generic-CUPS-PDF-printer - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: permissions, printing, pdf, customizer

Printing any document to a PDF works nicely. Unfortunately I want the created PDF file to be saved at a different location.

The current default location is: `/home/PDF`

The desired one location is: `/home/myname/DropBox/PrintWork`

I tried to edit the file containing the default directory for this kind of work: 
`/etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf`

Problem is that (I am the superuser) I don't get a permission to save the new default location.
When I look at 'permissions' everything is dimmed. 
I am a starting Ubuntu 14.04 user since 3 weeks.

I already spent a lot of hours to solve this, can anybody help me getting this right?

Comment: When and how you get the permission error? And how are you modifying the conf file? You should give more details...

Answer (score 2):

### How to change `cups-pdf` default directory

- it does not accept symlinks
- note that this method will change the behaviour for every users
- this is why you may have to use one of these variables:

  - `${HOME}` will be expanded to the user's home directory
  - `${USER}` will be expanded to the user name
- in this example, the output will go to `~/MyDocs/PDF`
- so you have to change the path according to your needs

#### 1. Edit `cups-pdf.conf`

```
gksudo gedit /etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf
```

- find and comment out this line (by adding `#` in front):

  ```
  Out ${HOME}/PDF
  ```

  like this:

  ```
  # Out ${HOME}/PDF
  ```
- then, add this line right below

  ```
  Out ${HOME}/MyDocs/PDF
  ```

#### 2. Edit `usr.sbin.cupsd`

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.cupsd
```

- add at the end of the file, edit the lines beginning with `@{HOME}` to match your desired location

  ```
  @{HOME}/MyDocs/PDF/ rw,
  @{HOME}/MyDocs/PDF/* rw,
  ```
- reboot to activate the changes

Comment: this worked for me on 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing permissions somehow... as root you should be able to edit it from a console (`sudo vi /etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf`) and change the `Out` setting to what you need.

An alternative: making ~/PDF a symlink, unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: See my answer here to make it work with symlinked folders: https://askubuntu.com/a/1353522/93798

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is about one year old, but for a ubuntu-beginner the simplest way to edit the file `/etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf` is to use the normal default editor gedit with sudo.

Therefore just open a Terminal and type `sudo gedit /etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf`

Then edit everything you'd like to... save the file and close gedit afterwards!

That's it.